# Calling my API always returns my index.php file. Why is this?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I created an **index.php** file in my public folder (Laravel), an API route in my **route/api.php** with the url `'submit'` and request method `post`, and a Controller with a function `submit()` that is executed on the API call.

I tried testing the route on Postman with the following url:

`http://mysite.local/api/submit`

This was tested as a `POST` request, but for some reason it keeps returning the **index.php** file.

I even added a `return "Test";` at the start of my `submit()` function in my Controller to see if the problem was with the code within the function (hope that makes sense, working on my terminology).

But yet again, when I test the API on post man, it still returns the **index.php**.

Here are my route and Controller:

**route/api.php**

```
Route::post('submit', 'SubmitFormController@submit');
// I've also tried the following:
// Route::post('submit', 'App\Http\Controllers\SubmitFormController@submit');
```

**SubmitFormController.php**

```
class SubmitFormController extends Controller {
    public function submit() {
        return "Test";

        /** .. More code below .. **/
    }
}
```

I even tried changing `return "Test";` to `return json_encode(['test' => 'testvar']);` thinking it would help. But Postman still returns the **index.php**.

My guess is that it's treating my API route as a "directory", but I may be wrong.

---

**UPDATE:** I noticed another strange (strange to me) thing happening.

So, when I go to my local host, which is `mysite.local`, it takes me to my `index.php` file in my public folder, which is what it should do. HOWEVER, when I then type in something like `mysite.local/skjah/asjdklasjd/asjdklasj` (which is clearly gibberish and not an actual directory), it redirects to `index.php` every single time.

So I'm assuming that because `api\submit` is not a directory in `public`, it just redirects to `index.php`. But I'm not sure why as this has worked in the past and my `.htaccess` has been untouched.

Hope this bit of information helps.

---

**UPDATE:** Just been fiddling with the code and noticed that the issue lies in my `.htaccess` as some of you have pointed out. Here is my `.htaccess` (straight out of the box when I made the project, didn't touch it).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I changed the line `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` to `RewriteRule ^ index123.php [L]` just to see what would happen and the API call to my route function no longer works. Which tells me it has something to do with this file.

That's as far as I got and still looking for a solution. Hope this helps clarify the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't your route be `Route::post('/api/submit', 'SubmitFormController@submit');` ?

Comment: How are you running your application? Are you running it with `php artisan serve` or are you using some setup like `xampp`?

Comment: @bassxzero - I tried that and the same issue happens.

Comment: @SasaBlagojevic - I'm using `wamp`.

Comment: Is it returning the source code of `index.php`?

Comment: @AkenRoberts - Yeah, exactly that. Like it just keeps redirecting to `index.php`.

Comment: @UndercoverCoder then you haven't set up your `wamp` correctly check if it allows for .htaccess files

Comment: @SasaBlagojevic -  API calls work for other projects using the same wamp settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue!!

I was trying to access a "customer" table in my controller and other files, when the actual table name is "customers".

***GIANT FACEPALM***

Hopefully this will help someone, check the spelling in your code before you end up stressing like me Haha.

Answer (score 1):

My user cant comment yet, so .. here it goes as a answer ...

By and large whenever this occurs it is some page server (this case apache) configuration issue, not php.

Considering you mentioned "routes" I assume you are using "

Have a look in your httpd.conf (and in the .htaccess) if you have something like the configuration below which would be missing or misconfigured (PS: time per time they change configurations, verify if the files in your configuration are compatible with the systems you are using - apache version and php version)

```
# PHP5 module
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

PS: API Calls (if using 80 or 443 port) should not work as well in this computer, if they do it tends to be misconfiguration on .htacces files.

Comment: The configuration is missing in both files, but when I add it in httpd.conf, wamp doesn't start up. And when I add it in the .htaccess, I get 500 Internal Server error when running my api.

Comment: As I said, you should check the configuration of your wamp services versions. I could try to help a little bit more, can you tell me which Operation System you have, which wamp version (3.17, 3.0.6) .. ?

Comment: I don't use wamp for a long time, but AFAIK it have a "button" for everything, check out this advice from a year ago: For running PHP scripts, “Apache” module needs to be turned on. To turn it ON, right-click on the “wamp icon” in the notification tray, then navigate to “Apache” section & turn it ON. ( NOTE :- Mostly Apache is automatically started when you run wamp, but if doesn't just follow the step-4). https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-start-a-PHP-in-a-wamp-server

Comment: I'm using wamp 3.1.7, on a 64-bit Windows 10

Comment: have you checked the tutorial i passed in the last comment? I guess it should be more useful them try to sort it out on configuration files for it is a wamp case!

Comment: I looked at the tutorial on setting up wamp and running a PHP script.. Followed through with it and Apache module is already on. Everything in my project works fine, apart from when I try call my api routes. I also spotted something I will post as an update in mt question which should help understand the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194345/discussion-between-ricardophp-and-undercovercoder).